My Junit test file has Unknown module: warnings
Please can you advise me? I'm using Java SE-21 and JUnit 5 in Eclipse JEE. I've just begun a course on JUnit and on setup my test file received the following warnings:
WARNING: Unknown module: junit5 specified to --patch-module
WARNING: Unknown module: junit5 specified to --add-reads
WARNING: Unknown module: junit5 specified to --add-opens

Test File is:
package com.in28minutes.junit5;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class StringTest {

    @Test
    void test() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

}

Here's a screenshot of the project set-up.

I'm trying to run the StringTest class as a JUnit Test in Eclipse JEE.
I expected the code to run with no errors and 1 failure.
The result was the code didn't run through the test due to some configuration issue. I got 3 warnings instead:
WARNING: Unknown module: junit5 specified to --patch-module
WARNING: Unknown module: junit5 specified to --add-reads
WARNING: Unknown module: junit5 specified to --add-opens

